# Set property From other module prism

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I have wpf application with Prism and mvvm architecture in 1 module i have a treeview and in other module i have textbox.Both modules are loading properly.
What i want to do is 
-Click treeview node.
-set currently selected object in viewmodel.
-also fire an event(or something else) and set the node value to textbox in other module

First two points are working properly.
Its the third i cant figure out.

Here is my treeview code.

```
 <TreeView Name="TreeViewTest" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path= TestObservable}">

        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">                
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Tag="{Binding Id}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

Code where I am setting selected object.

```
    private bool _selected = false;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return _selected;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_selected == value) return;
            _selected = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            this._selectedItem = this;               
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Name);

        }
    }
```

and the viewmodel isSelected is a child Viewmodel of main viewmodel that actually binds the treeview module.

So it s as follows

```
public interface ITreeViewModel
{
    ITreeViewModelView { get; }
    ObservableCollection<IChildTreeViewModel> TestObservable{ get; set; }

}
```

Any help would be great

Answer (score 1):

Well,Prism says I have four ways for communication between modules:(Event Aggregator,Shared Service,Region Contex and Commanding) and I add another way sharing objects through the Container.
However,I believe in your case the best is (Event aggregator or sharing through the Container.

**Event Aggregator:**

1)Define an event in a project which all modules have access to it (Infrastructure.dll for instanse).
 this event have to inheriet form CompositePresentationEvent. YourObjectClass is the class of data you want transfer between modules:

```
namespace Infrastructure
{
 public class ObjectChangedEvent: CompositePresentationEvent<YourObjectClass>
 {       
 }
```

2)Inject the event aggregator to both source and target modules' view models

```
 IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
    private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;
    private readonly IUnityContainer _container;
    private Creator _creator;

    public NavigationViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator, IRegionManager regionManager, IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        _regionManager = regionManager;
        _container = container;
    }
```

3)Publish the defined Event from the source view model,As target view model has subscribed it already.
in the target view model:

```
 eventAggregator.GetEvent<UnCheckEvent>().Subscribe(CheckHandler);
```

in the source view model:

```
eventAggregator.GetEvent<UnCheckEvent>().Publish(YourObject);
```

4)It is obvious that finally you should implement CheckHandler method that gets your object and you can set it to the property which is binded to your textbox .

I hope this could help